# Call a ruby array in external javascript from Haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, haml

I'm new to RoR and web app development, Im using Rails 3.2.3 and I want to use a ruby array in Highcharts and I'm using Haml in my view files.

I have an array defined in the controller like so:

```
...
def show
  ...
  @close_array = DailyQuote.where(company_id: @company.id).map(&:closing_price)
end
```

and I've declared it in my Haml view file.

```
%body
  - close_array_j = "#{@close_array.inspect}"
  =javascript_include_tag :build_chart
  #container{:style => "min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"}
```

Now I want to use this array, `close_array_j`, in a Highcharts chart which I've written the code for in a separate file called build_chart.js:

```
$(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      },
...
    series: [{
      name: 'Closing Price',
      data: $('#close_array_j')
    }]
...
```

The highcharts chart is being rendered with no data. By the way, I dont know ruby or haml or js very well as you can probably tell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print the variable like this in HAML

```
%script
  != "close_array_j = #{@close_array.to_json};"
```

and then use it in javascript

```
...
series: [{
    name: 'Closing Price',
    data: close_array_j
}]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable assignment you do in your haml view file has no effect. It doesn't automagically apply itself in your javascript file.

You could wrap it up in a script tag. Here's the erb version:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
 close_array_j =  = '<%= j @close_array.to_json %>';
<% end %>
```

However, there are other, cleaner techniques. One would be to leverage the HTML5 data attribute to embed data such as yours. It's easy to access with Jquery.

I recommend you watch Ryan Bate's screencast on how to pass data to javascript in a variety of ways.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast